# How to get values to listview or tableview from database in Android?

Tags: android, listview, tableview

I have database called wisherDB, and I have a table called tbltasks inside the database.

The Table simply has colmmn names of `id`, `title`, `name`, `date`, `time`, and `type`.  I want to get id, name, and the time to relate to the current date, and I can access current date by a Calendar class, so that is not the problem.

The selection code is in a seperate class called `DataAccess` and code is mentioned below.

What I want to do is get the details from the query and display it on the tableview.  I tried this without selection of date[where clause][that means select * from ...] that is working for this.

But with the selection, it's not showing the data.

DatabaseAccess class Select query:

```
public Cursor getTasktoDate(String Date) throws SQLException
{
    Cursor mCursor=db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID,KEY_TASKNAME,KEY_TASKTYPE}, KEY_TASKDATE+"="+ Date, null, null, null, null, null);
    if(mCursor!=null)
    {
        mCursor.moveToFirst();
    }
    return mCursor;
}
```

And this is the code of the activity:

```
    Cursor c=dba.getTasktoDate("2011/10/12");
    if (c.moveToFirst())
    {
      do {
        DisplayContact(c, tltodaytask);
      } while (c.moveToNext());
    }
    dba.Close();
}

private void DisplayContact(Cursor c, TableLayout tltodaytask) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String id=c.getString(0);
    String tName=c.getString(1);
    String tType=c.getString(2);
    insertRow(tltodaytask,id,tName,tType);
}

private void insertRow(TableLayout tltodaytask, String id, String tName,
        String tType) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    final TableRow newrow = new TableRow(this);

    addTexttoRowswithValues(newrow, id);
    addTexttoRowswithValues(newrow, tName);
    addTexttoRowswithValues(newrow, tType);
    tltodaytask.addView(newrow);
}

private void addTexttoRowswithValues(TableRow newrow, String text) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    TextView textview = new TextView(this);
    textview.setWidth(115);
    textview.setText(text);
    newrow.addView(textview);
}
```

This method not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have problem in

```
Cursor mCursor=db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, 
        new String[] {KEY_ROWID,KEY_TASKNAME,KEY_TASKTYPE}, 
        KEY_TASKDATE+"="+ Date, null, null, null, null, null);
```

You should use

```
Cursor mCursor=db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, 
        new String[] {KEY_ROWID,KEY_TASKNAME,KEY_TASKTYPE}, 
        KEY_TASKDATE+"= ?", new String[]{Date}, null, null, null, null);
```

Comment: 1 small thing... if i want to search for 2 value for equality like Date and Time.... what should i change in the parameter section....

KEY_TASKDATE+"= ?" AND KEY_TASKTIME+= ?", new String[]{Date,Time}
Is this correct...!!!!!!!